# How to draw the below image in android programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, draw, android-framelayout

I am new to android. I'm finding very difficulty in using the Canvas. How to draw the below image in android? I also want to make the alphabet selected highlighted when it is touched.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have each item as independent view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="64dp"
        android:background="#000">
        <!-- Main area -->
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#f00"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#0f0"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/c"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#00f"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/d"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#ff0"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/e"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#0ff"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/f"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#f0f"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/g"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#900"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/h"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#090"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/i"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#009"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/l"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#990"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/k"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#099"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/j"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#909"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

**EDITED**

You also can do this within one view with help of canvas:

```
public class GameView extends View {
    private final int[] colors = {
            0xffff0000, 0xff00ff00, 0xff0000ff,
            0xffffff00, 0xff00ffff, 0xffff00ff,
            0xff990000, 0xff009900, 0xff000099,
            0xff999900, 0xff009999, 0xff990099};

    private final Paint[] paints = new Paint[colors.length];
    private Paint mainAreaPaint = new Paint();

    private RectF mainAreaRect;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float squareSize = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 7;

        //draw main area
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(squareSize, squareSize, 6 * squareSize, 6 * squareSize), mainAreaPaint);

        //draw top squares
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(2 * squareSize, 0, 3 * squareSize, squareSize), paints[0]);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(3 * squareSize, 0, 4 * squareSize, squareSize), paints[1]);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(4 * squareSize, 0, 5 * squareSize, squareSize), paints[2]);

        //draw right squares
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(6 * squareSize, 2 * squareSize, 7 * squareSize, 3 * squareSize), paints[3]);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(6 * squareSize, 3 * squareSize, 7 * squareSize, 4 * squareSize), paints[4]);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(6 * squareSize, 4 * squareSize, 7 * squareSize, 5 * squareSize), paints[5]);

        //draw bottom squares
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(4 * squareSize, 6 * squareSize, 5 * squareSize, 7 * squareSize), paints[6]);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(3 * squareSize, 6 * squareSize, 4 * squareSize, 7 * squareSize), paints[7]);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(2 * squareSize, 6 * squareSize, 3 * squareSize, 7 * squareSize), paints[8]);

        //draw left squares
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(0, 4 * squareSize, squareSize, 5 * squareSize), paints[9]);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(0, 3 * squareSize, squareSize, 4 * squareSize), paints[10]);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(0, 2 * squareSize, squareSize, 3 * squareSize), paints[11]);
    }

    private void init() {
        for(int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            paints[i] = initPaint(colors[i]);
        }

        mainAreaPaint = initPaint(0xff000000);
    }

    private Paint initPaint(int color) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        return paint;
    }
}
```

Sorry about bad-performance-code. Of course you need to place all initializations of Rects in onMeasure method and properly handle andoird xml attributes like minHeight and e.t.c. Also it's is up to you to write right positioning of drawed paining inside view (in center, in corner e.t.c), but I just wrote a sample to catch main point. Here is screenshot, what we have in the end:

[image]

Comment: How to draw this programmatically? I am really sorry I didn't mention it

Comment: I will add to my answer how you can draw it with canvas.

Comment: Yeah! I am really excited to see that!

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope, you will appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great.Can you please add it with drawing text. Finding difficulty in adding text

Comment: You need to use canvas.drawText. Something like canvas.drawText("Test", 0, 4, 0, 0, paint);
more info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: In my code i should show this View on multitouch when I tap second finger on screen. And the Centre of view should appear at my point of touch. I am working from 2hrs and not able to figure it out. The main difficulty I am facing in mapping the screen coordinates values for left, top, right, bottom values

Comment: @JohnPabba could you please describe more details what your actual problem, you cannot get coordinates of your touched fingers? You cannot compute center of touch from finger coords? Or you can not pass this center coordinates to view to compute its coordinates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118066/discussion-between-john-pabba-and-michael-spitsin).

Comment: Maybe you could create a question to your specific problem, so me and other users will able to help to you?